# Getting the resource into controller

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I'm in trouble getting my service inside the controller. This project is under
the lastest yeoman which creates the templates for me and merges the files when build.

When changing something the angular just stops working and no error is displayed in console.

The error message is :

```
ReferenceError: UserService is not defined
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/people.js:5:25
at invoke (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:2864:28)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:2874:23)
at http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:4759:24
at <error: illegal access>
at Object.Scope.$broadcast (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:8261:28)
at http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:7417:26
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:6797:59)
at wrappedCallback (http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:6797:59)
at http://localhost:9000/components/angular/angular.js:6834:26
```

App.js :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jellybeanApp', ['jellybeanApp.Service'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })
  .when('/people', {
    templateUrl: 'views/people.html',
    controller: 'PeopleCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
 });
```

My service :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jellybeanApp.Service', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('UserServices', function ($rootScope, $resource, $routeParams, $location) {
return {
  users : function() {
    return $resource('notimportant',
      {action: 'user', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
      {
        get: {method: 'JSONP', params: {UserId: $routeParams.UserId}},
        query: {method: 'JSONP'},
        create: {method: 'POST'}
      });
  }
};
});
```

Controller :

```
'use strict';

angular.module('jellybeanApp')
 .controller('PeopleCtrl', function ($scope, UserServices) {
$scope.userResult = UserService.users().query();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting `UserServices` into your controller, but then trying to access `UserService`. Looks like a simple typo?

Comment: wow, that that did the trick, Thank you so much. If you look to long you apparently miss the obvious. Should I mark this thread as answer or just delete it ?

Comment: @ArniReynir I would personally appreciate an accepted answer =)

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, I would drop the

```
  {action: 'user', callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'},
  {
    ...
    create: {method: 'POST'}
  });
```

And only use built in UserService.users.$save()
*edited for typo